# Какие однокоренные слова можно подобрать к слову "увлекаться"?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

-

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, "однокоренные" пишется через О. Во-вторых, предложение начинается с большой буквы. В-третьих, слово "увлекаться" должно быть в кавычках. В-четвертых, в конце вопросительного предложения ставится вопросительный знак. А в-пятых, однокоренные слова: "влечь", "влечение", "завлечь", "привлечь", "влекомый", "увлечение". Достаточно?